# How to pass a program argument via run configuration in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I am running a Python program and I want to pipe the output to file. So in python this command is

```
 "python myfile.py > output.txt"
```

I'm running the program via pydev in Eclipse, how can I pass in the parameter "`> output.txt`" to the run configuration within Eclipse ? There does not seem to be this option :

[image]

When I try as above I receive the error :

```
C:\Python27\python.exe: can't open file 'output.txt': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Run configuration of your project -> Open "Common" tab -> find the "Standard input and output" tab. Check "File" and select the file where you want the output to go.

[image]

Comment: thanks but that does'nt explain how to pass a parameter into python program, in this case pydev has an alternative for appending to a file. What if I wanted to read the parameter within the python program ?

Comment: There is a separate tab for arguments in the run configurations and you have shown it. JFYI, `>` is not an argument (nor parameter), but an operator to direct the output, which is implemented on lower level.